# pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix different from single pgr_Dijkstra, error: direction choose wrong way verse

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I've a graph (no OSM) and I try with 14 of 468 nodes to resolve this problem.

System: Ubuntu Server + Postgres 14 + pgRouting 3.5

[image: Screenshot of problem]

When I use pgr_TSP() function I use pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix() with Edges and my 14 Nodes, with directed=>true,
but in the screenshoot is wrong the sequence 12-13-14.

I try to analize the result with pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix() and pgr_Dijkstra():

**SQL1**

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM dbroute_pl_generic_edges', 
    (
      SELECT 
        array_agg(id) 
      FROM 
        dbroute_pt_generic_nodes
    ), 
    directed => true
  ) foo 
WHERE 
  start_vid = 13800066621912 
  AND end_vid = 13800002893438
```

**SQL 2**

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  pgr_Dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM dbroute_pl_generic_edges', 
    13800066621912, 13800002893438, 
    true
  )
```

Node in screenshoot > id

`-- 13 > 13800066621912`

`-- 14 > 13800002893438`

**Result SQL1**

| start_vid | end_vid | agg_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13800066621912 | 13800002893438 | 17 |

**Result SQL2**

| seq | path_seq | start_vid | end_vid | node | edge | cost | agg_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 13800066621912 | 13800002893438 | 13800066621912 | 13800013628133 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 13800066621912 | 13800002893438 | 13800002442093 | 13800002073213 | 1 | 1 |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| 17 | 17 | 13800066621912 | 13800002893438 | 13800002442092 | 13800001198905 | 1 | 16 |
| 18 | 18 | 13800066621912 | 13800002893438 | 13800002893438 | -1 | 0 | 17 |

The result is correct!

[image: Screenshoot simultate Dijkstra]

But in TSP is wrong!

**SQL3**

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  pgr_TSP(
    $$ 
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix(
        'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM dbroute_pl_generic_edges', 
        (
          SELECT 
            array_agg(id) 
          FROM 
            dbroute_pt_generic_nodes
        ), 
        directed => true
      ) bar $$
  ) foo
```

**Result SQL3**

| seq | node | cost | agg_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 13 | 17 | 13800066621912 | 4 |
| 14 | 18 | 13800002893438 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

This mean that the cost from 13 to 14 is only 1 and not 17!

[image: Screenshot result pgr_TSP]

I try in different part of graph, with few nodes and sometimes I get the same error, but this is the most highlight.

I'm expeting that pgr_TSP get result egual to pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix